# API POST call from Console Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webapi

How to do the REST API POST Call from the console Application ?

I want to pass the class from the Console application to the REST API. My below code is working if I have to do the GET call but not for the POST. It is hitting the API but in the Parameter it is not passing anything.

API

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values

    //public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    //{

    //}
    public void Post([FromBody]Student value)
    {

    }



}
```

Console Application

```
 static async Task CallWebAPIAsync()
    {

        var student = new Student() { Id = 1, Name = "Steve" };

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Send HTTP requests from here. 
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:58847/");
              client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/values", student);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Internal server Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

The Same is working if I call from fiddler.

User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Length: 31
Host: localhost:58847
Content-Type: application/json

Request Body:
{
"Id":"1",
"Name":"Rohit"
}

Comment: What errors you are getting?

Comment: You coud try to remove the line that clears the headers.

Comment: No Error I am getting. The Student object in API is null. And I tried removing the line also which clears the header.

Comment: Have you tested the API Post call with [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or [Curl](https://curl.haxx.se/)?

Comment: Yes, with Fiddler I have tested. It is giving the value in the API. If I call in this way- User-Agent: Fiddler Content-Length: 31 Host: localhost:58847 Content-Type: application/json

Request Body: { "Id":"1", "Name":"Rohit" }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working for me.

```
    public async Task CallWebAPIAsync()
    {
        var student  = "{'Id':'1','Name':'Steve'}";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:58847/");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("api/values", new StringContent(student, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        if (response != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have another issue. How Can I pass the data in the API POST call if it is to be in this format  public class Student
    {       


        public string commandText { get; set; }
        public CommandType commandType { get; set; }
        public IDbDataParameter[] parameters
        {
            get; set;

        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You are not serializing the student object. 
You can try to send a StringContent

```
StringContent sc = new StringContent(Student)

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/values", sc);
```

if this doesn't work (a long time I used StringContent).
 Use NewtonSoft sterilizer

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/values", output);
```

Comment: I have tried both still not working. Any changes I need to do the API end ?

Comment: I don't think that you need to do any API configuration because the default model binding is JSON. And you mention it worked in Fiddle? Before we make anything drastic could you try encoding it?                 StringContent sc = new StringContent(Student,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                var data = await client.PostAsync(Student, sc);

Comment: This is working. Thanks. But what was the issue with the above code. Can you explain ?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't know. It seems like your StringContent did not sterilize it to UTF8 which your restful API is trying to do by default. However, your console application should also do that by default.

The issue seemed to be that the restful API could not bind the byte data and therefor not assign the data to your class Student in the restful API.

What you can try to do is add following code before you make your post to API:

```
var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
```

It will tell you what is your default encoding type. It could be that UTF8 is not the default encoding for some reason.

Comment: I have another problem now. How can I pass the data of this call in the API Post call  public class Student
    {       


        public string commandText { get; set; }
        public CommandType commandType { get; set; }
        public IDbDataParameter[] parameters
        {
            get; set;

        }
    }